# The pandas group the rows in the dataframe based on the repeated values in the column and repeat all after an Uniqe ID value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

*Input DataFrame

```html
  
 `  C1       C2
0  WID  94556
1  LB  INTRO:
2  FNAME  Misg, Hugh
3  NAME  Misg H
4  AD  NY, USA.
5  FNAME  Iqbal, Zee
6  NAME  Iqbal, Z
7  AD  302, Paris, Fransh.
8  FNAME  Talega, hama
9  NAME  Talega h
10  AD  New York, USA. suresh@usa.us
11  AD  Delhi, New Delhi,
12  OTO  NOTNLM
13  OTO  Nano
14  OT  Nano
15  WID  1564576
16  OM  20181211
17  LB  INTROD:
18  FNAME  Mik, Jeb
19  NAME  Mik, J
20  AD  SB,UK,
21  FNAME  Bala, E
22  NAME  Bala E
23  AD  Paris, Fransh.
24  LA  eng
25  OTO  NLM
26  OT  agents
27  OT  Nano
```

Now I need to group the dataframe based on the column values(corresponding values separated by ";") and I should get the following (=Number of WID#) different rows.

I tried this `df=df['C2'].groupby([df.C1],sort=False).apply('; '.join).reset_index()`
but it is grouping every unique elements in column and I want in row like bellow ("WID" will be different according to dataset)

Input dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1' : ['WID', 'LB', 'FNAME', 'NAME', 'AD' ,'FNAME', 'NAME', 'AD','FNAME', 'NAME', 'AD','AD', 'OTO','OTO', 'OT','WID','OM','LB','FNAME','NAME','AD','FNAME','NAME','AD','LA','OTO','OT','OT']
      ,'C2' : ['94556', 'INTRO:','Misg, Hugh'
               ,'Misg H','NY,  USA.',' Iqbal, Zee'
               ,'Iqbal, Z',' 302, Paris, Fransh.','Talega, hama','Talega h','New York, USA.  suresh@usa.us','Delhi, New Delhi,'
               ,'NOTNLM','Nano','Nano','1564576','20181211',' INTROD:',' Mik, Jeb','Mik, J','SB,UK,','Bala, E','  Bala E','Paris, Fransh.','eng','NLM',' agents','  Nano']})
```

The expected output is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9Onj.png)

Comment: I have made a mistake(both WID# = 94536) in the output image, the WID1 and WID2 will be different according to given dataframe, in given dataframe it is **ID** and it is 94556 and 1564576.

Comment: I have updated Input dataframe. (Made changes: ID to WID)

Comment: What is the source of your data? Are you trying to read data from a text file into a `dataframe`? It would be great if you can simplify the problem here by providing us a [**minimal**, complete and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes, it was a big .text data file that I filtered it and converted it in to a dataframe. This data is about documents and **WIDs** are documents id and **FNAMEs**, **NAMEs** are corresponding document's Authors name and **ADs** are the corresponding authors  adresess. above I have given example data about two documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an image in the link, I think you can achieve it with the following code. If the same columns exist, they need to be pre-combined.

```
df['new_idx'] = 0
cnt, w = 0, 0 
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['C1'].iloc[i] == 'WID':
        cnt +=1
    df['new_idx'].iloc[i] = w + cnt

df2 = df.pivot(values='C2', index='new_idx', columns='C1').fillna('')
df2 = df2.iloc[:,[10,6,4,1,5,0,2,9,8]]
```

Comment: Thanks, @r-beginners Using your above idea I got satisfactory output but the problem is it is taking too much time if I'm using it over a large data.csv (40k rows)  `df2['new_idx'] = 0
cnt, w = 0, 0 
for i in range(len(df2)):
    if df2['C1'].iloc[i] == 'WID':
        cnt +=1
    df2['new_idx'].iloc[i] = w + cnt`

Comment: and I'm getting these suggestions:- [http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy]/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
**Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead**